# Number of Combinations (considering transitivity) in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I have question and a solution. But the solution doesnt seem to be satisfy all test cases :

Question:

variable N denotes the naming boundary(0,N-1)
variable K denotes the number of test cases

each test case is of format (x,y)...(a,b)

such that if (x,y) is given x,y belongs to same class
and if (x,y) and (y,z) is given x,y,z belongs to same class

The output should be number of possible ways of selecting  2 items from different class

Solution :

```
inp=raw_input()
inp1=inp.split(' ')

n=int(inp1[0])
k=int(inp1[1])

classes=[[]for i in xrange(0,n)]
no_classes=0

def in_list(c):
    for i in range(0,no_classes):
        if c in classes[i]:
            return i;

    return -1



for i in range(0,k):
    inp=raw_input()
    inp1=inp.split(' ')
    c1=int(inp1[0])
    c2=int(inp1[1])

    l1=in_list(c1)
    l2=in_list(c2)

    if l1<0 and l2<0:
        classes[no_classes].append(c1)
        classes[no_classes].append(c2)
        no_classes+=1
    elif l1>=0 and l2<0:
        classes[l1].append(c2)
    elif l2>=0 and l1<0 :
        classes[l2].append(c1)
    elif l1>=0 and l2>=0 and l1!=l2:
        classes[l1]=list(set(classes[l1]+classes[l2]))
        del classes[l2]
        no_classes-=1        

tot_combntns=0;

for i in range(0,no_classes):
    for j in range(i+1,no_classes):
        tot_combntns=tot_combntns+len(classes[i])*len(classes[j])

print tot_combntns 


Sample test case : 

6 3
0 1
2 3
4 5

ans : 12

5 4
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4

ans = 0 because there is only one class(0,1,2,3,4)
```

But I am not sure this solution satisfies all test cases

Comment: It is unclear from your text what you are trying to achieve, and your code sample uses such poorly chosen variable names that it does not help understand your goal. You might be looking for [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) but that's a pretty wild guess.

Comment: Is this a programming challenge? (I have an odd feeling it's an automatic interview question.)

Comment: @msw : Sorry for my bad code...you need to find number of possible combinations (2 items per combination from different class)

Comment: @user2357112: yes its a practice programming challenge..

Comment: Isn't there a two classes in a last test case? One for 0,1,2,3,4 and one for 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a practice programming challenge, I won't get you the answer.  I will tell you enough to figure it out if you are competent.  I'm leaving it at what I consider a reasonable difficulty level.  If you're capable of creating objects, performing recursion, etc, then it should be straightforward.  If you're not capable of that, then failing this programming challenge is a sign that you need to learn more basics.

If you have a group of `n` items, the number of ways of picking a pair from them is `n*(n-1)/2`.  The number of ways of picking a pair from different classes is the number of ways of picking a pair minus, for each class, the number of ways of picking a pair from that class.  The challenge is, therefore, to find the classes and count each one.

Figuring out that two elements are in the same class can involve many possible chains of reasoning.  For instance the rules `(a, b), (x,y), (b, y)` imply that `a` and `x` are in the same class.  How do you efficiently go through all possible reasoning chains?  A simple and efficient method is to create an object that can take any element and map it to the smallest known member of its class.  (Under the hood it suffices for it to map every element that is not minimal to a smaller known one, and lazily figure out the smallest known one on demand.)

Figuring out how to implement that object I leave as an exercise.  As is, once you have it, figuring out how to count how many are in each class.

Comment: i figured the solution and coded it..but except for 2 all of the test cases are working fine...thanks